# cocos2d-js displays only one type of tile from a tmx file

Tags: javascript, cocos2d, tiled

I am using **Tiled** to produce a `tmx` which I use in my code using **cocos2d-js**.
The problem is that when I run it on the browser, a wrong tile gets displayed, the first one of the image (0,0) and repeats for the whole map.
The relevant js code is this:

```
this.farm = new cc.TMXTiledMap(res.farm_tmx); 
this.addChild(this.farm);
```

where `res.farm_tmx` the path to the tmx file.

What could be the source of the problem? And how do I fix it? It seems to me that it is specific to my code. I do not find any other reports of the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to preload the tileset image?
Besides preloading `"res/farm.tmx"`, you may have to preload, say, `"res/farm.png"`.
I had the same problem, and that solved it for me.